# Run interactive shell within nested ssh connection in script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell, sudo

Suppose I want to connect to machine B via machine A. As I learned, there are multiple ways to achieve this, for example

```
ssh -T -J user@machineA user@machineB << END_OF_SSH_CONNECTION
  # Some commands in machine B
END_OF_SSH_CONNECTION
```

or

```
ssh -T user@machineA << END_OF_MACHINE_A
  ssh -T machine B << END_OF_MACHINE_B
    # Some commands in machine B
  END_OF_MACHINE_B
END_OF_MACHINE_A
```

However, it is not clear to me how to start an interactive shell where the user can type commands when connected to machine B. For example, this works:

```
ssh user@machineA -t 'bash -l -c "bash"'
```

and this does work as well:

```
ssh -J user@machineA user@machineB -t 'bash -l -c "bash"'
```

The following does not work, however:

```
ssh -J user@machineA user@machineB -t 'sudo apt-get update; bash -l -c "bash"'
E: Command line option 'l' [from -l] is not understood in combination with the other options.
Connection to machineB closed.
```

And neither the following:

```
ssh -J user@machineA user@machineB -t 'if [ 1 -eq 1 ]; then bash -l -c "bash"; fi'
/usr/local/sbin/start_ttylog.sh: line 67: exec: if: not found
Connection to machineB closed.
```

I also tried this:

```
ssh -T -J user@machineA user@machineB << EOF

  # Some commands on machineB

  # Check whether apache2 has been correctly installed
  if [ $(dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' apache2 2>/dev/null | grep -c "ok installed") -eq 1 ];
  then
    printf "done\n";
  else
    printf "fail\nStarting an interactive shell: enter exit to quit\n";
    bash -l -c "bash";
  fi
EOF
```

This last version almost works (i.e. it returns no errors), but it does not start an interactive shell where the user can type commands as I would expect.

I hope someone is able to help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, @attie. I slightly modified your proposed code, which I report here below

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env bash
>
> ssh -T -J user@machineA user@machineB 'cat >/tmp/myscript' <<"EOF"
> if dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' apache2 2>/dev/null | grep -q 'ok installed'; then
>   echo "done";
> else
>   echo "fail, starting an interactive shell";
>   bash -l -c "bash";
> fi
> EOF
>
> ssh -t -J user@machineA user@machineB "bash '/tmp/myscript'"
> ```

into this, which does not even need to write to an external file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ssh -T -J user@machineA user@machineB << "EOF"
if dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' apache2 2>/dev/null | grep -q "ok installed"; then
  echo "done";
else
  echo "fail, starting an interactive shell";
  bash -l -c "bash";
fi
EOF
```

I was basically missing the quotes around `EOF`, used to avoid an attempt at expanding field `${Status}`.

Comment: I am not convinced this will work out (see my answer)... Does the `bash` command in your "_failure_" case work as expected? The quotes around `EOF` aren't an explanation for it not working before (given your errors), but would be an explanation for other things going wrong later!

Comment: @Attie it just works: if the package is not installed, it prints the fail string and opens an interactive shell, where I can type commands. I can just type `exit` and the shell closes.

Comment: But with your invocation you won't get an interactive shell, because of the `-T` and `<< "EOF"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a script on the remote host *and* get an interactive shell, then you have two options:

1. Put the whole script into the command line arguments for `ssh`.
2. Push the script to the remote host (e.g: using `scp` or `ssh`), and then execute it (e.g: using `ssh`)

---

## 1. Script in Args

Your last example is on the verge of "*long*" for this approach, but you can help with readability by using [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-mapfile) (a builtin in `bash`). Note the quoted `"EOF"` to avoid an attempt at expanding `${Status}`.

```bsh
mapfile -t SCRIPT <<"EOF"
if dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' apache2 2>/dev/null | grep -q 'ok installed'; then
  echo "done";
else
  echo "fail, starting an interactive shell";
  bash -l -c "bash";
fi
EOF

ssh -t -J user@machineA user@machineB "${SCRIPT[@]}"
```

## 2. Push Script, Then Run

Bonus points for using `mktemp` and cleaning up afterwards. Note quoted `"EOF"` again.

Based one of your supplied error messages (around `exec`, see below for more), this use of `cat >/tmp/myscript` will probably not work out.

```bsh
ssh -T -J user@machineA user@machineB 'cat >/tmp/myscript' <<"EOF"
if dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' apache2 2>/dev/null | grep -q 'ok installed'; then
  echo "done";
else
  echo "fail, starting an interactive shell";
  bash -l -c "bash";
fi
EOF

ssh -t -J user@machineA user@machineB "bash '/tmp/myscript'"
```

---

Step one should always be to try to break the problem down into the simplest form... re your last incantation, try the following instead:

```bsh
ssh -T user@machineA << EOF
  bash -l -c "bash";
EOF
```

What happens? You'll get any welcome messages from the remote host, but then the session immediately and silently ends without error.

Changing `-T` (explicitly *disable* PTY allocation) for `-t` (force PTY allocation) provides a hint in the right direction:

```bsh
ssh -t user@machineA << EOF
  bash -l -c "bash";
EOF
```

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

This is pointing out that you're using `stdin` to provide a script, and then also attempting to connect that same `stdin` (a pipe, not a terminal) to the remote PTY.

So let's remove the `stdin` factor:

```bsh
ssh -t user@machineA bash -l -c "bash"
```

And it works!

Fundamentally you *cannot* share stdin with both a script and a terminal.

---

As for the other errors:

```
E: Command line option 'l' [from -l] is not understood in combination with the other options.
```

Again, break it down to find the issue. Unfortunately these commands work for me, I suspect because the systems I have access to are using `sh -c "${ARGS}"` or similar. However, another error you've provided gives a hint:

```
/usr/local/sbin/start_ttylog.sh: line 67: exec: if: not found
```

It looks like your system is using `exec` to run the command given as arguments to `ssh`... which means the shell isn't able to handle things like `if` or `;` for you as you are hoping - so `if` isn't a binary on the path and it fails.

Equally, all of the arguments are given to `sudo` at once:

1. `sudo`
2. `apt-get`
3. `update;`
4. `bash`
5. `-l`
6. `-c`
7. `"bash"`

Sure enough, `sudo`'s `-l` (list) argument is mutually exclusive with `-c` (login class).

Comment: Let's see if I understood correctly. The easiest way would be creating a script, push it on machineA with scp, ssh into machineA, push the script on machine B, ssh into machineB and then run that script from there.
The other way is to use `mapfile`, which I am not sure what it is actually (there is no man page and it is not available in my distro's repo), but it is not clear to me how to execute it on machineB from the local machine.

Comment: You can push directly to machineB using `ssh -J machineA machineB ...`

Comment: `mapfile` is a shell builtin, at least it is for `bash`... try `help mapfile`

Comment: I see! I am using `zsh`, so that explains it. Everything is clear, now, thank you. The only issue I am facing is that cat is complaining like this: `cat: '>/tmp/myscript': No such file or directory` but it does not make much sense to me, since it should create the file on the fly, right?

Comment: @Michael Your setup is non-standard, probably it has something to do with `start_ttylog.sh`. Apparently `cat >/tmp/myscript` is not interpreted by a shell. For whatever reasons `cat` gets `>/tmp/myscript` as a literal name of a file.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, I fixed the problem by removing the dependency on `cat` by putting EOF between double quotes. This works and there is no need to write and read an external file.